# cannot understand what callback does in a Connect module

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, node.js-connect

I am reading a book about NodeJs Connect. There is this small part about `basicAuth` module. I know that `basicAuth` is now deprecated, but I cannot understand this simple code. The book says

> Providing an asynchronous callback function
>
> The final option is similar, except this time a callback is passed to
>   basicAuth() with three arguments defined, which enables the use of
>   asynchronous lookups. This is useful when authenticating from a file
>   on disk, or when querying from a database.
>
> Listing 7.7. A Connect basicAuth middleware component doing
>   asynchronous lookups

[image]

And no other information. Thats the whole part about having a callback in the `basicAuth`

So, code gets the username and the password. Then hypothetical object `User` has a method `authendicate` that checks if this user actually exists. And when its finished, calls the `gotUser` function. `gotUser` contains either a returned error (=no user found with that username/password) or a returned user object (a user found with that username/password). Am I right?

`gotUser` checks if there is an error. If there is, returns and calls `callback` with an error argument. So wait, what will `callback` do at this point? Its not defined anywhere. Will it pass the error to an error handler function? And how?

If there is not an error, `gotUser` calls `callback` again with `null`(= no error) and `user`. Once again, what will callback do? Why pass the returned user to the callback and not grab its name, mail, age etc etc and use them on a session or fill the `innerHTML` of a tag or whatever?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So wait, what will `callback` do at this point? Its not defined anywhere.

The value of `callback` is defined by the `basicAuth` middleware.

You can find its definition within the [`basic-auth-connect` module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/basic-auth-connect), used by [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/2.30.2/lib/middleware/basicAuth.js), in the module's [`index.js`](https://github.com/expressjs/basic-auth-connect/blob/1.0.0/index.js#L83-L87):

```
callback(user, pass, function(err, user){
  if (err || !user)  return unauthorized(res, realm);
  req.user = req.remoteUser = user;
  next();
});
```

When `gotUser()` invokes `callback(...)`, it's call the `function(err, user){...}` from the above snippet, passing the `err` and/or `user` along to be used.

---

And, how they're used, in the two scenarios you were wondering about...

> `gotUser` checks if there is an error. If there is, returns and calls `callback` with an error argument. So wait, what will `callback` do at this point?

> If there is not an error, `gotUser` calls `callback` again with `null`(= no error) and `user`. Once again, what will callback do?

The `if (err || !user)` condition will pass for both (one has an error, the other is lacking a user). It then considers the request `unauthorized` and will end the response immediately.

```
function unauthorized(res, realm) {
  res.statusCode = 401;
  res.setHeader('WWW-Authenticate', 'Basic realm="' + realm + '"');
  res.end('Unauthorized');
};
```

---

> Why pass the returned user to the callback and not grab its name, mail, age etc etc and use them on a session or fill the `innerHTML` of a tag or whatever?

The middleware is applying [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), keeping itself as small and concise as possible. It's goal is just to determine a `req.user` and validate it.

When it's done that successfully, other middleware in the application's queue will be able to reference the `user` that was found. This can includes using it to render markup from a view:

```
// determine the user
app.use(connect.basicAuth(...));

// now make use of it
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  viewEngine.render('view', { user: req.user }, function (err, result) {
    if (err) return next(err);

    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.end(result);
  });
});
```

Note: This is generalized and won't run as-is. You'll need to find and setup a view engine of your choice and substitute that into the snippet.

---

Also, side note on...

> fill the `innerHTML` of a tag

Though Node.js is executing JavaScript, it's doing so within its own environment, completely detached from any browsers. It's not possible to interact directly with the DOM currently seen by the user.

Comment: Great answer. One last question about the callback. This line `req.user = req.remoteUser = user;` says that the parsed user that tried to login (`req.user`) now equals the authenticated one (`user`). But what is the `req.remoteUser`? Thanks again

Comment: `req.remoteUser` was the previous name for `req.user` [used by Connect 1.x](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/blob/1.9.1/lib/middleware/basicAuth.js#L78). In later versions, `req.user` is the intended property, but it continues to set `req.remoteUser` for compatibility. So, it's just a duplicate reference to the `user` provided to the `callback()`.

Comment: Thanks again for the answer

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of different things going on. For one, app.use expect a function that will be called with req, res, and next. When you run connect.basicAuth, it runs this method.

Since this is a middleware method, this method will run every time a route that was defined after this method is hit.

The second thing that is going on is connect.basicAuth is a function that will be called with username, password, and a callback method. Callback is something that connect.basicAuth provides.

If you return callback(err), it will send a 401 Not Authorized back to the client. If you return callback(null, user), it will continue until either the next middleware function, or the appropriate route.

Comment: Nice answer. Thank you very much.